# 301 redirect for webpage, not domain

Tags: url, redirect, dns

Can I use a 301 redirect for a url.

For example: I want to be able to automatically redirect a page url i.e.

```
http://www.somesite.com/somepage
```

to

```
http://www.somesite.com/some_new_page
```

Can I accomplish this using 301 redirect, or is a 301 redirect meant for domains only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use this status for permanent redirection.

Make sure to return this status number in conjunction with the `location` [header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location);
The value of the `location` header should be the URL you wish to redirect to.

Comment: I am still uncertain whether the redirect will make me to visit the domain, or it will send me to the new page url that I specify.

Comment: The page you are redirected to is the one specified in the location header; what do you mean by 'visiting the domain'?

Comment: I meant if I added a redirect for http://www.somesite.com/somepage to http://www.somesite.com/some_new_page, and try visiting the page http://www.somesite.com/somepage, then it will direct me to http://www.somesite.com/some_new_page as I specified, not to http://www.somesite.com/. Thanks for clearing my confusion.